# how to get image data

Tags: php, forms, image, file, symfony4

I want get image data to crop and after then save

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Entity\Services;
    use App\Form\ServicesType;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

    class CreateServiceController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/create/service", name="create_service")
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {

            $service = new Services();
            $form = $this->createForm(ServicesType::class, $service);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                $service = $form->getData();
                $service->setCreated(new \DateTime('now'));

                /** @var UploadedFile $imagereFile */
                $imageFile = $form->get('image')->getData();

                if ($imageFile) {
                    $originalFilename = pathinfo($imageFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                    $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
                    $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$imageFile->guessExtension();

                    try {
                        $imageFile->move(
                            $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                            $newFilename
                        );

//problem here
                        $croped = \imagecrop( $this->getParameter('image_directory').$newFilename, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
                        imagejpeg($croped, $this->getParameter('image_directory').$newFilename, 75);
                    } catch (FileException $e) {
                        // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                    }
                    $service->setImage($newFilename);
                }

                // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
                // for example, if Task is a Doctrine entity, save it!
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($service);
                $entityManager->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('services');
            }

            return $this->render('update_service/index.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I have this code but it does not work

```
Warning: imagecrop() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

> //problem here
>
> $croped = \imagecrop( $this->getParameter('image_directory').$newFilename, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100]);
>
> imagejpeg($croped, $this->getParameter('image_directory').$newFilename, 75);
>
> } catch (FileException $e) {
>
> // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
>
> }
>
> $service->setImage($newFilename);
>
> }

Comment: The error is literally telling you what's wrong. The function you use expects the image itself, not just the path. You just need to select the proper function to create the image based on the type of image you're using.

Comment: thank you I try do this